# Make online link for application in softvare center

Tags: software-center, application-development

is it possible to make online link for an application which is located in ubuntu software center. I need to advertise my app and I don't know how to make link for my app (I don't have website).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web interface with install button for the software center: https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/

Or just make a link with: apt://appname

Comment: weird thing is that I can't find my app on this online software center, but on real software center I can find it. And also apt://skrywer works, thank you :)

Comment: It takes up to 24 hours to show up on that site after it has been published on the USC

Comment: I published application 3 days ago and still I can't find it on online softvare center.